# Sonar: Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting issue from Sonar: "Style - Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method. findbugs:NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE.
the issue is on lockUntil.after(new Date());

```
try {
            String sql = "select lock_until from shedlock where NAME=?";
            Timestamp lockUntil = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {taskname}, Timestamp.class);
            
            return lockUntil.after(new Date()); //issue line
            
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
            LOGGER.info("Checking shedlock for locked task[" + taskname + "]. No task exists. Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

I've tried to change this issue line with

```
Date date = new Date();
return lockUntil.after(date);
```

or

```
Date date = new Date();
if(date != null)
    return lockUntil.after(date);
else
    return false;  -> this line is dead end
```

But it introduces other issues.

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `new Date()` will never return `null` should be a valid assumption.   My guess is that the possibly `null` value Sonar is complaining about is `lockUntil`.  I assume that `queryForObject` will return `null` if the query does not match any rows, so it makes sense that you'd get a complaint about using `lockUntil` without first checking if it is `null`.

Comment: I've also tried  if(lockUntil != null) {
    LOGGER.info("Checking shedlock for locked task[" + taskname + "] Lock_until[" + lockUntil + "]"); 
    return lockUntil.after(new Date());
   } else
    return false; but it introduces other issues. Did I miss something?

Comment: You should put that comment in your question.  You might also explain what those "other issues" are.  Were you able to confirm that it was the `lockUntil` that it was complaining about?

Comment: Steve, I fixed the issue now by adding both of them, date and lockUntil.